# Viewing edit diffs

Tags: feature-request, editing, markdown

Here are three views of [an edit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/25221/revisions) (screenshot of my Windows desktop Chrome browser).

I'm posting these as a sample because [DVK said](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/25217/did-fox-news-win-a-court-case-for-the-right-to-lie#comment95030_25221) he sees all of them as a wall of red/green text.

Post an answer (or edit this question) if you see something radically different (and less usable), and therefore want to turn this into a bug report about what you're seeing.

---

## Inline

[image]

## Side-by-side:

[image]

## Side-by-side markdown

[image]

Comment: From the paragraph labelled 2 and onward I also just see a bunch of red then the replacement as a bunch of green. No way to tell easily what content has been just reformatted or actually changed in meaning. The edit is huge and really difficult to tell point by point what changed.

Comment: Scroll down further in your inline changes example to see what we mean. The beginning is fine.

Comment: Its not a bug. Its just the nature of the edit.

Comment: @spoderman Is that true even when you specifically select the 3rd, "Side-by-side markdown" view using those buttons near the top-left?

Comment: No, but selecting side-by-side markdown for one edit doesn't make all the edits into that view only the one that is selected. Maybe that's a usability bug.

Comment: But what's all this about. Why can't we just read the current content and see if it needs improvement? Why does it matter what it used to be

Comment: If someone else edited my post then I would want to use the 'diff' view to see what they have changed. That's a habit of programmers: to ensure that no unwanted/bad changes slip in among a bunch of acceptable changes.

Comment: I didn't know this was a programmers community :) also I saw the cc licence and assumed that meant things were more wiki-like here, with answers not belonging to anyone. I get it noe though

Comment: Yes I should have put "my" in inverted commas. A few people are on this site, because they were on StackOverflow (a related programmers' site) before this one. If checking the diffs seems excessively cautious, ascribe it to curiosity then instead of caution. :)

Comment: Well, what's the *expected* behavior of the diff? It's clearly comparing the HTML render, which is different (the original has one, the modified one has multiple lists).

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze - based on the name, I'd expect the Markdown diff to diff the underlying markdown.

Comment: @DVK the markdown diff is the third, the other two are HTML diffs

Comment: @ChrisW - yeah, it's a usability thing, not a bug. I was expecting the view setting to reflect on ALL previous edits. 
spoderman had it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False alarm. It was a usability fail (I'd rather blame it on design, than on the faulty interface between chair and keyboard. But realistically speaking, probably the latter :)

I was expecting that the view switch would control the diffs for **all** revisions, and didn't realize I have to adjust the view for the specific revision I was looking at instead of the one at the top.